# How to paginate in Core Data while inserting new items in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app that shows data from DB in a table view. In my application I have to check with server if new items are available. If yes, insert new items into the DB in background without blocking the user.User may be scrolling the table while new items are inserted. How to achieve this without affecting pagination so that user can see the newly inserted items also?.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle the fetch for you. Providing you are correctly merging `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` into your main context then `NSFetchedResultsController` will correctly fetch the results and update your table view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the properties of NSFetchRequest

1. fetchBatchSize
2. fetchLimit
3. fetchOffset

[NSFetchRequest Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFetchRequest)